# Android back button not going right activity And How to handle Activities in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Am creating small application using login, register and user details. After login am going to store login credential to shared preference and navigate to dashboard activity. In second time  directly navigate to dashboard activity. This level of code is working fine.

Please consider I have three activity **MainActivity, LoginActivity, RegisterActivity, DashboardActivity and ProfileActivity.**

In my **MainActivity** If user value is sharedPreference directly moving to **DashboardActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(new SessionManager(getApplicationContext()).isLoggedIn()){               
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class));
        }
    }
```

In my **DashboardActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
```

Now am simply press back button in device goes to **MainActivity** not **DashboardActivity**. I want to move activity to **DashboardActivity** only, not **MainActivity**. Please guide me how to do that. And how to handle session in Android.

Also I have bit confusion in using which flags and where to use. I tried in **DashboardActivity** but not working.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent newIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
                newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(newIntent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Now I tried various possible ways but not getting solution.

Main problem occurs after navigating **DashboardActivity** to any Activity won't come back to **DashbarodActivity** instead of going **MainActivity**. I don't know why it happens. Any problem in **MainActivity** navigation

Comment: while going to next activity finish the previous activitys in onClick() which you no need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about that, but in `DashboardActivity` try to start your activity like this: `startActivity(new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));`

Comment: Hi Damien, thanks for reply. I tried your way, not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED ANSWER:**

on your **ProfileActivity**, try to override onBackPressed method then start the DashboardActivity again and don't forget to finish the current activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    startActivity( new Intent(this, DashboardActivity.class) );
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Hi heri, I need to do ProfileActivity to DashboardActivity, not ProfileActivity to MainActivity.

Comment: Oh sorry, i've missed that. If that so, i think your code would work just fine. I'm not sure about this, but you may try to change method isLoggedIn of SessionManager class into static one (so you can just call it by: SessionManager(getApplicationContext()).isLoggedIn() )

Comment: I tried, but unable call like this `SessionManager(getApplicationContext()).isLoggedIn()`

Comment: Oh my fools! Sory, that wouldn't be work, just forget it. By the way, i just edited my answer and hope that would work nice :)

Comment: Thanks for your involvement, your code always move DashboardActivity. In future I may increase my activities. ex: new activity **ListFriendsActivity** I navigate to **ProfileActivity**. And Now what will happen when I press back button.

Comment: yeah, its just another 'tricky' way if no more options available. But, it is really not recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

Just finish the current activity after starting the new one via Intent and you should achieve the desired functionality and this way you don't need any flags. Except for the MainActivity of course.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I tried finish() in MainActivity, After I clicked totally apps closed. And also I tried with DashboardActivity moves to MainActivity. Not what I expect. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply override onBackPressed method in your ProfileActivity and call finish method.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   finish();
}
```

Comment: Hi @shylendra, I tried your code now total apps closed. I don't want to close app. Need to move **ProfileActivity** to **DashboardActivity**. Main problem occurs after navigating **DashboardActivity** to any Activity won't come back to **DashbarodActivity**